# How to create sub-milestones of a milestone in Jira?

Tags: jira

Is it possible to create sub-milestones of a milestone and create different tasks under sub-milestone and create sub-tasks under task?

```
(parent)milestone => (child)sub-milestone_1 => sub-milestone_1_task_1 => sub-milestone_1_task_1.1
```

Comment: Yes you can create sub-tasks under tasks. I don't know about the others but that's in my opinion something you should frind out from google or the user guide: https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/jira-user-s-guide-100303115.html and not a question for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need multilevel hierarchy of issues.

Jira supports only two levels: issue and sub-issue.

You can try the [Structure](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.almworks.jira.structure/server/overview) plugin. If you want a different (and free) approach try by referring to the issues hierarchy just with **issue links** like "derived by", "relates to", etc.